# Worklog for windows

Tags: python, windows, time-tracking

Is there an analogue of [this tool](http://ajy.co/2010/worklog-a-simple-time-tracking-program/) (maybe python/ruby/etc) which runs under windows?

[image]

It has minimalistic but very convenient interface (ncurses-based) close to command-line.

Most operations can be done via two keystrokes.

NB I've read [Best commandline time tracking application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398344/best-commandline-time-tracking-application) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624466/simple-and-free-time-tracking-software but found nothing appropriate.

Comment: Why not install cygwin and compile the worklog program and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure-Python solution see [**timed**](https://github.com/adeel/timed). It's very simple to use and provides a tab-completion by editing `.bashrc`:

```
$ timed start myproject
starting work on myproject
  at 16:35 on 07 Feb 2011

$ timed
working on myproject:
  from     16:35 on 07 Feb 2011
  to now,  17:00 on 07 Feb 2011
        => 0h25m have elapsed

$ timed stop
worked on myproject
  from    16:35 on 07 Feb 2011
  to now, 17:40 on 07 Feb 2011
       => 1h5m elapsed

$ timed summary
myproject   1h5m

$ cat ~/.timed
myproject: 16:35 on 07 Feb 2011 - 17:40 on 07 Feb 2011

$ cat ~/.timed | grep "Jan 2011" | timed parse
```